# GCC Extended ASM syntax: load 128-bit memory location as source

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, sse

GCC generates this code for the shuffle() below:

```
movaps xmm0,XMMWORD PTR [rip+0x125]
pshufb xmm4,xmm0
```

Ideally this should be:

```
pshufb xmm4,XMMWORD PTR [rip+0x125]
```

What is the extended ASM syntax to generate this single instruction?

Many thanks,
Adam

PS: The commented out intrinsic generates the optimal code for this example. This doesn't work in general (GCC is likely to generate unnecessary register copies in the presence of global register variables).

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef int8_t xmm_t __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));
const xmm_t xmm_shuf={128, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
register xmm_t xmm __asm__("xmm4");

#define NTL ".intel_syntax noprefix\n"
#define ATT ".att_syntax\n"

void shuffle() {
  //xmm=__builtin_ia32_pshufb128(xmm, xmm_shuf);
  __asm__(NTL"pshufb %0, %1\n"ATT : "=x" (xmm) : "x" (xmm_shuf));
}

int main() {
}
```

$ gcc -Os -std=gnu99 -msse4.1 -flax-vector-conversions pshufb_128bit_constant.c && objdump -d -m i386:x86-64:intel a.out |less

```
0000000000400494 <shuffle>:
  400494:       0f 28 05 25 01 00 00    movaps xmm0,XMMWORD PTR [rip+0x125]        # 4005c0 &lt;xmm_shuf+0x10&gt;
  40049b:       66 0f 38 00 e0          pshufb xmm4,xmm0
  4004a0:       c3                      ret
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the input operand's constraint to `"xm"`, so that memory locations are allowed in addition to SSE registers.

However, when I tested it, the compiler generated code that doesn't sit well with Intel syntax. So, in the end, this is what I used:

```
__asm__("pshufb %1, %0" : "+x" (xmm) : "xm" (xmm_shuf));
```

Comment: Many thanks Chris! I was stumped by the Intel syntax. Very impressed with your help.